# TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXX' of null

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

- Puppeteer version: **1.0.0**
- OS version: **Mac OS**
- Node.js version: **8.9.1**

Error log:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`

[here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/RicoLiu/0w9sd61t/4/)

I am in trouble.Can anyone helps me?

Comment: Please paste you proper code how any now about this a very small explanation

Comment: The error log should also show you on which line it occurred. It should be fairly simple to figure out after knowing the line. Quite likely one of the querySelector does not return an element and you are trying to read value of our innerText  property.

Comment: [I submitted an issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2098)